# Interpreting "pairwise"

Tags: geometry, definition, geometric-interpretation, parsing

I have the following exercise.

> Can four lines in space (not necessarily passing through the same point) be pairwise perpendicular?

---

Does it mean (given 4 lines $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$):

- $a\perp b$; $b\perp c$; $c\perp d$; and $d\perp a$

or

- $a\perp b$, $a\perp c$, and $a\perp d$; $b\perp c$ and $b\perp d$; and $c\perp d$

?

---

### ***How is "pairwise" to be interpreted?***

---

**NOTE:** I do NOT need help solving the exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that all pairs of lines are perpendicular.

Skipping redundant pairs

a is perpendicular to b.

a is perpendicular to c.

a is perpendicular to d.

b is perpendicular to c.

b is perpendicular to d.

c is perpendicular to d.

Answer (score 1):

Pairwise *(something)*: any/every pair from the set are *(something)*.

The question is asking: Can you have a set of four lines such that if you select *any/every* pair of them they are perpendicular?

Or does $\{(a,b,c,d): a\perp b, a\perp c, a\perp d, b\perp c, b\perp d, c\perp d\}=\varnothing$ ? (empty set.  ie: Is it that there are no such set?)

Comment: Thanks! A side question: what does the Ø mean?

Comment: Empty set.  Or in this case it means "There is no possible examples of this".